# Create unique and similar list among three columns in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a dataset from three different sources of the same variable that needs to be consolidated. The three columns need to be combined into one based on similar rows. Three more columns need to be created showing values not in the union of the three.

Here's the data:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
1       1       1
2       2       2
3       4       4
5       5       6
6       6       7
8       8       8
```

Desired result:

```
Combined_column_name  Unique_column1  Unique_column2 Unique_column3
1                     3               4              4
2                     5               5              6
8                     6               6              7
```

**Edit: Attempted Method**

I got the distinct values separate from the duplicate, but not in separate columns.

Step 1: Combine into one column

```
Combined
1
2
3
5
6
8
1
2
4
5
6
7
1
2
4
6
7
8
```

Step 2: Do `=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)=1` and filter only true to show unique

```
Combined    TEST
3           TRUE
6           TRUE
8           TRUE
1           TRUE
2           TRUE
5           TRUE
6           TRUE
```

Step 3: Copy `TRUE` and `FALSE` values into other columns. Remove duplicates for 
FALSE

```
Combined    TEST    DISTINCT    DUPLICATE
1           FALSE   3           1
2           FALSE   6           2
3           TRUE    8           5
5           FALSE   1           4
6           TRUE    2           7
8           TRUE    5           6
1           TRUE    6           8
2           TRUE        
4           FALSE       
5           TRUE        
6           TRUE        
7           FALSE       
1           FALSE       
2           FALSE       
4           FALSE       
6           FALSE       
7           FALSE       
8           FALSE
```

Comment: Interesting. What have you tried already?

Comment: Is the data numerical? Or was that just your example?

Comment: @Raystafarian I found a way of filtering out the duplicates after eliminating the distinct rows. I still need to separate the distinct rows into columns according to the columns they came from. First step involves putting all the columns into one, then using a COUNTIF() function and show TRUE for distinct, but FALSE for similar. Here's a link to a similar method: http://superuser.com/questions/705991/how-to-remove-non-duplicate-records-in-excel-2010

Comment: @Excellll The data is all numerical.