# In Excel, how to keep two years of data together based on a common data point?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of data from 2015-2016 and want to keep the two years together based on a common data point.  I would also like to exclude anything that does not have both years on file because I only care about the year to year change, so single values are just clutter.

So my table looks something like this.  I want to take out the "oranges" line.  Thanks!

edit: and by "apples" "pears" etc., I mean, unique reference numbers--these being the data point that I would like to connect the years to.

```
2015    apples  4   $0.79
2016    apples  2   $0.83
2016    oranges 14  $1.12
2015    pears   22  $0.74
2016    pears   17  $0.79
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a formula that return 2 for the connected items and 1 for non duplicate:

`=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$8,2015,$B$1:$B$8,B1)+COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$8,2016,$B$1:$B$8,B1)`

$A$1:$A$8 the year column change it to correspond your Data and keep $
$B$1:$B$8 the fruit column change it to correspond your Data and keep $
B1 the fruit that you want to count
Drag the formula down the column
Sort all the Data by the countifs 2 will be together and 1 together, you can delete the rows with 1

Comment: Just saw yours after I posted. FAR more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the MOST elegant solution but it works.

In your example, I would sort by Column A then by Column B so all of your data is in the format above predictably. Then, add these statements:

```
2015    apples  4   $0.79         $STM2  $STM3
2016    apples  2   $0.83  $STM1  $STM2  $STM3
2016    oranges 14  $1.12  $STM1  $STM2  $STM3
2015    pears   22  $0.74  $STM1  $STM2  $STM3
2016    pears   17  $0.79  $STM1         $STM3
```

So for line 2 that $STM# are equal to:
$STM1 =

```
=IF(B2=B1,TRUE,FALSE)
```

$STM2 =

```
=IF(B2=B3,TRUE,FALSE)
```

$STM3 =

```
=IF(E2=F2,TRUE,FALSE)
```

For all entries where $STM3 = TRUE, delete the line. In my example it looked like this:

```
2015    apples  4   $0.79          TRUE   FALSE
2016    apples  2   $0.83   TRUE   FALSE  FALSE
2016    oranges 14  $1.12   FALSE  FALSE  TRUE
2015    pears   22  $0.74   FALSE  TRUE   FALSE
2016    pears   17  $0.79   TRUE          FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the linked duplicate:

1. Create a new helper column, using `=COUNTIF($B$1:$B$5, B1)` at the start of the column, and drag it down to the end of range.

[image: Helper column]

2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to turn **Filtering** on.

[image: Filtering on]

3. Click on the **little down arrow** on the helper column, and uncheck `TRUE`

[image: Filter out TRUE values]

4. It will leave you with only `FALSE` values. Select all rows with `FALSE` and delete them.

**Note:** the topmost row is considered header and thus will **always visible regardless of the value**.

[image: Only FALSE]

5. Again, click the little down arrow, and check back the `TRUE` values. Then you can turn off **filtering** by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Taken, and adapted, from: [How to remove non-duplicate records in Excel-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/705991/how-to-remove-non-duplicate-records-in-excel-2010)